# How to disable the tooltip dynamically in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I can disable the tooltip statically.
But I want to disable tooltip dynamically when i click flatbutton.But Couldnt disable dynamically and i have no idea to do that.
If I give statically false. it works fine.
For example : If add child like TopToolbar(showTooltip : false),it works fine,
But If i give toolbar.showTooltip = false in Flatbutton onPressed method,it doesnt work.
I want to disble it in dynamically. please help me to do that.
This is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main(){
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: HelloWorld(),debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,));
}
class HelloWorld extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HelloWorldState createState() => _HelloWorldState();
}

class _HelloWorldState extends State<HelloWorld> {

  bool check = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Center(
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
              TopToolbar(),
              FlatButton(
                child: Text("Disable Tooltip"),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    TopToolbar toolbar = new TopToolbar();
                    toolbar.showTooltip = false;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ]),
          ),
        ));
  }
}

class TopToolbar extends StatefulWidget {

  bool showTooltip;
  final Color backgroundColor;
  final double height;
  bool isVisible;
  TopToolbar({
    this.height = 55,
    this.isVisible = true,
    this.backgroundColor = const Color(0xFFEEEEEE),
    Key key,this.showTooltip=true,
  }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _TopToolbarState createState() => _TopToolbarState();
}

class _TopToolbarState extends State<TopToolbar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (widget.isVisible) {
      return Container(
        foregroundDecoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border(
            bottom: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 1),
        color: widget.backgroundColor,
        height: widget.height,
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Positioned(
              top: 7,
              right: 60,
              height: 40,
              width: 40,
              child: RawMaterialButton(
                elevation: 0.0,
                fillColor: widget.backgroundColor,
                splashColor: Colors.grey[300],
                child: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.bookmark,
                    color: Colors.grey[500],
                    size: 25,
                  ),
                  onPressed: (){},
                  tooltip: widget.showTooltip ? "Bookmark" : null,
                ),
                onPressed: (){},
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return Container();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please don't ask the same question multiple times.

Comment: Have you tried my solution?

Answer (score 1):

You have to store whether to show the tooltip in `_HelloWorldState`, not in the `TopToolbar`.

This would lead to doing something like this in `_HelloWorldState`:

```
class _HelloWorldState extends State<HelloWorld> {
  bool showTip = true;
  bool check = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Center(
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
              TopToolbar(showTip),
              FlatButton(
                child: Text("Disable Tooltip"),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    showTip  = false;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ]),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

`showTooltip` should also be marked as `final` in `TopToolbar` class.

Your current implementation creates a new `TopToolbar` widget, it doesn't modify the existing widget. `TopToolbar toolbar = new TopToolbar();` creates a completely different widget, just one that isn't ever mounted and shown. Therefore, `toolbar.showTooltip = false;` has no visible effect.

Alternatively to what I have shown you can access of the `State` of the `TopToolbar` using a `GlobalKey`, but I wouldn't recommend this for a beginner, it isn't necessary for your implementation at the moment, and `GlobalKey`s are relatively expensive.

Answer (score -1):

This is too simple buddy,
make 1 global variable below main method

`bool isTooltipActive = true;`

Now change onPressed method like this

```
FlatButton(
    child: Text("Disable Tooltip"),
    onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
            if(isToolTipAvtive == false){
                isToolTipAvtive = true;
            }else{
                isToolTipAvtive = false;
            }
        });
    },
),
```

And change bookmark tooltip line like this

`tooltip: isToolTipAvtive ? "Bookmark" : null,`